# Accessing property values in F# constructors

Tags: constructor, f#

Sorry if this is basic, but I'm still wrapping my head around F#.

I want to do this:

```
type Person(user:User) as this =
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    user.UserId <- this.Name
```

But that gives me the error `Unexpected identifier in member definition`.

This compiles:

```
type Person(user:User) as this =
    do 
       user.UserId <- this.Name
    member val Name = "" with get, set
```

But gives me an `InvalidOperationException` at runtime.

I've settled for this:

```
type Person(user:User) =
    member val Name = "" with get, set

    member this.Setup() = 
       user.UserId <- this.Name
```

But I don't like having to call `person.Setup()` each time.

What's the best F-Sharpy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an explicit constructor to force the code for initializing the member functions to be run before your other code as follows

```
type User() = 
    member val UserId = "" with get,set 
type Person private ()  =
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    new (user:User) as this =
        Person()
        then user.UserId <- this.Name
```

This is due to the fact that the initializer code is run in the constructor, so you must force it to run to completion before acccessing the properties

Comment: Is there a way to do that and only allow the second constructor (passing in the User object) to be called? I.e., some way of making the first (explicit) constructor private?